# Advance a Date in Java (including leap years and year changes.)

Tags: java, class, object, testing

So I have to complete a MyDate class, and the requirements are to advance the date, without using any imports/etc. The code that I have now is a start to what I have, and I have already included the leap year portion, but need the section that adds a day, or when the day reaches say 31, add a month and bring the day back to 0.

```
  private int year;
  private int month;
  private int day;

  //Constructors (1) and (2)
  public MyDate(int d, int m, int y){
      this.year = y;
      this.month = m;
      this.day = d;
  }

  public MyDate(int y){
      this(1, 1, y);
  }

  //Accessors for the three instance variables
  public int getYear(){
       return year;
  }
  public int getMonth(){
       return month;
  }
  public int getDay(){
       return day;
  }

  //The advance method as stubbed out below
  public void advance(){
       MyDate test = new MyDate(day, month, year);

     if(day <= 31 && day >= 1){
        test = new MyDate(day += 1, month, year);

        if(day > 28 && month == 2 && year % 4 != 0){
            test = new MyDate(day -= 28, month += 1, year);
        }


     }
  }
```

These are two test cases given in order to check if the date increases.

```
    //TC 1 : 1/31/2013 advances to 02/01/2013
    date = new MyDate(31,1,2013);
    date.advance();
    correctDate = new MyDate(1,2,2013);
    if(date.equals(correctDate)){
        System.out.println("TC 3 passed");
    }else{
        System.out.println("TC 3 failed");                
    }

    //TC 2 : 02/28/2013 advances to 03/01/2013
    date = new MyDate(28,2,2013);
    date.advance();
    correctDate = new MyDate(1,3,2013);
    if(date.equals(correctDate)){
        System.out.println("TC 4 passed");
    }else{
        System.out.println("TC 4 failed");            
    }
```

Any answer would be nice, I am new to this and will try to answer any questions you may have.

Comment: Please provide the attributes of your MyDate class. We don't really know how you are implementing it.

Comment: Will do! Give me one moment.

Comment: Alright I just added the instance variables, the two constructors that I've implemented, and the accessors to the instance variables, hope this helps!

Comment: Hint: I'd start with writing a (potentially private) `getDaysInMonth(int year, int month)` method. I'd also personally advise making the type immutable, with `advance` returning a new `MyDate` object. It's much easier to reason about that way, IME.

Comment: The test cases uses `equals` to compare dates. The default implementation of equals() inherited from `Object` considers two objects to be equal only if they are the same instance. You'll want to override the default implementation to compare the fields of the objects, so that two different MyDate instances are equal to each other if they have the same field values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jon Skeet mentioned, you should first create a method that will return the number of days in a specific month. For example, if you ask for the number of days in May, it will return 31; if you ask for the number of days in February it will return either 28/29 depending on whether that month is a leap year.

That method could be as simple as having a huge list of if-else-if statements.

e.g.

```
getDaysForMonth() {
  if (month == 1) { // January
    return 31;
  }
  else if (month == 2) { // February
    // special case, will have to do some more complex checks here :)
    // you may already have these conditions in your question body
    if (/* year is a leap year */) {
      return 29;
    }
    else {
      return 28;
    }
  }
  // and so on ...
}
```

With the method above, you need only call it from your `advance()` method and check if the day needs to be increased or reset to 1:

```
advance() {
  int lastDayThisMonth = getDaysForMonth();

  if (day == lastDayThisMonth) {
    // reset day to 1
    // increase month (also have to know whether it's the last month and reset it accordingly)
    // (hint: modulo operator % is your friend)
    // possibly increase year (if month gets reset to 1 too)
  }
  else {
    // increment day
  }
}
```

Some data types declarations were omitted and some statements I wrote out as comments so that you may write it in code yourself. I think you will get the overall idea.

*Note: the constructs above are supposed to mutate the original object. If you are looking for an immutable version, you should return a new MyDate object as Jon Skeet also mentioned.*